# Galaxy S2 Messaging: persistent badge number

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, samsung-galaxy-s-2, notifications

I use a Galaxy S2, SPH-D710VMUB (Virgin Mobile) running Android 4.1.2
The default messaging app it comes with has this (very common) feature of showing a little red circle with the number of new text messages in it. When you read your messages the icon disappears and you are left with just the yellow envelope icon.

[image: Notification badge]

Lately it has been displaying "3" new messages whether I have new messages or not. It never goes away, always the little red circle and the "3" inside it. 
My notifications tab at the top of the screen is properly updated, if I have no messages it does not display anything.
It doesn't seem to affect any of the other apps, notifications or functions of the phone. It's almost as if the icon simply never refreshed or something.
I have already restarted the phone, cleared RAM in Active Applications, etc.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

1. Head to **Settings**
2. Scroll down to find **Application manager**
3. Scroll to the right until you reach the page **All**
4. Locate **Badge-provider**
5. Click on **Clear data**, if you cannot click clear data then first hit **Force stop**, then you should be able too.
6. Restart your phone

([Source](http://iknowthatnow.com/2012/12/30/samsung-galaxy-s3-indicating-a-message-even-though-there-isnt-one-solved/))